# Saving HTML hardcoded table row data into XML file

Tags: servlets, saxparser, domparser

I am new to Java technology. I want to know if there is a way where we can save HTML table row data into XML file using either SAX or DOM parser API.

Here is the HTML/JSP code where the hardcoded value needs to be saved into XML file.

```
<tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selName" value="0" /></td>
                        <td>AJ's Gas Station</td>
                        <td>1234 Jackson Street</td>
                        <td>Atlanta</td>
                        <td>GA</td>
                        <td>30008</td>
                        <td>AJ Smith</td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selName" /></td>
                        <td>Mart 24</td>
                        <td>867 Peachtree</td>
                        <td>Atlanta</td>
                        <td>GA</td>
                        <td>30409</td>
                        <td>Bob Kent</td>
                    </tr>
```

The above code resembles two checkboxes events/inputs, where by if user clicks either any one or both of the checkboxes, all the data inside the  tag needs to be saved into XML file. Please help me with any suggestions you have.

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow this tutorial provided in this link https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/162988/convert-html-file-into-xml-using-java